# Need help compiling detour function

Tags: c++

I try to compile this dll for MW2. It will not compile due to the fact that detour function is undefined.

Here's the code:

```
// dll_load.cpp : Defines the initialization routines for the DLL.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using std::string;

typedef void (*SV_GameSendServerCommand_t)(int clientNum, /*svscmd_type*/int type, const char *text);
SV_GameSendServerCommand_t SV_GameSendServerCommand = (SV_GameSendServerCommand_t)0x822548C8;

typedef int (*Key_IsDown)(int ClientNum, int ButtonEnum);
Key_IsDown button_Pressed = (Key_IsDown)0x82141308;

typedef void* (*R_RegisterFont_t)(char* asset, int imagetrack);
R_RegisterFont_t R_RegisterFont = (R_RegisterFont_t)0x8234DC20;

typedef void (*R_AddCmdDrawText_t)(const char *text, int maxChars, void *font, float x, float y, float xScale, float yScale, float rotation, const float *color, int style);
R_AddCmdDrawText_t R_AddCmdDrawText = (R_AddCmdDrawText_t)0x823501E8;

typedef bool (__cdecl * Dvar_GetBool_t)(const char * dvarName);
Dvar_GetBool_t Dvar_GetBool = (Dvar_GetBool_t)0x8229EEE0;

void AddCmdDrawText(char* Text, int Unknown1, void* Font, float X, float Y, float Unknown2, float Unknown3, float Unknown4, const float *Color, int Unknown5)
{
    void* font = R_RegisterFont("fonts/smalldevFont", 1);
    float color[4] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    R_AddCmdDrawText("undefined", 0x7FFFFFFF, font, 100, 400, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   color, 0);
}

typedef void ( _cdecl* tRenderStuff )(); 

tRenderStuff oRenderStuff=0; 

void hRenderStuff() 
{ 
    void* font = R_RegisterFont("fonts/smalldevFont", 1);
    float colorWhite[4] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
    R_AddCmdDrawText("undefined", 0x7FFFFFFF, font, 100, 400, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, colorWhite, 0);

oRenderStuff(); 
} 

DWORD WINAPI commands(LPVOID)
{
        for(;;)
        {
            if (Dvar_GetBool("cl_ingame"))
            {
                oRenderStuff = (tRenderStuff)DetourFunction( ( PBYTE )0x585830, ( PBYTE )&hRenderStuff );     //hook endframe
            return 0;
        }
        Sleep(45);
    }
    Sleep(45);
}




BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HANDLE hInstDLL, DWORD reason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    if(reason==DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
      CreateThread(0,0,commands,0,0,0);
    }
  return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Please modify your source to *not* include obscenities.

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: sorry im fairly new to c++ and the terms

Comment: [Obscenities](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/obscenities) is not a programming term. I've made the changes for you. Further, you are attempting to call `DetourFunction` but you never define what `DetourFunction` does. Hence the error. Why are you calling it?

Comment: im calling it to change the api, I think thats what im going about.

Comment: heres the tut Im trying to follow but im just having trouble understanding http://pastebin.com/f6559d448

Comment: Are you trying to create a MW2 hack?

Comment: I wonder which obscenities is @Byte56 talking about... :3

Comment: @jskiles1 ya, im injecting a dll into the game on console

Answer (score 1):

Your code is missing this include:

```
#include <detours.h>
```

Which is likely the header file that has the definition for `DetourFunction`. Try to just compile the exact code in the tutorial first, then make your changes from there. Recompile/test after each change you make, then you'll know which change broke the code and you won't have to backtrack so much.

Comment: ok ive done some changes, still no success.

do you think you could possibly teamviewer

Comment: I can teamviewer if you can paypal ;) I charge $156 an hour for coding related tech support. I suggest starting from a known good example. Use the tutorial and try building that. If that's not working, update your question to include exact error messages.

Comment: I understand -_-

I have literally been trying everything, so im just going to follow your instructions and then update later.